# How do sort the elements by type(int, float, str) that fall from the input list to the output list?

Tags: python, list

There is a list from the user:

```
user_list = [1, 3.5, "xx", "gg", 6, "2"].
new_list = []
```

How to make it so that with the help of "list comprehension" from user_list to new_list moved:

1. Value with type (float)
2. Even number with type(int)
3. All elements that have type (str) turned into -2 and were sent to a new_list

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good candidate for a list comprehension since the logic seems too complicated for a single expression. Also -- you never said what is supposed to happen with odd integers, even though your sample input contains such things.

Comment: could you post how you expect your `new_list` to look like?

Answer (score 1):

not a good way to achive result but, using `list comprehension`

```
>>> user_list = [1, 3.5, "xx", "gg", 6, "2"]                  
>>> new_list = [*[i for i in user_list if type(i)==float], *[i for i in user_list if type(i)==int], *[-2 for i in user_list if type(i)==str]]
>>> new_list
[3.5, 1, 6, -2, -2, -2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using one list comprehension, this should give you `new_list` :

```
new_list = [(lambda x : -2 if type(x)==str else x)(x) for x in user_list if ((type(x)==float) or (type(x)==int and x%2==0) or (type(x)==str))]
```

As others have mentioned, a list comprehension is probably not the standard way to compute this result.